# Avidemux latest compiled for Linux?

Tags: avidemux

Is there a compiled version of [Avidemux nightly](http://www.avidemux.org/nightly/) for Linux.

Or is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is a [ppa for the latest Avidemux](https://launchpad.net/~rebuntu16/+archive/ubuntu/avidemux+unofficial).

For Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-gtk avidemux2.6-qt4
```

---

Also (the latest version being 2.6.10), following [this source](http://sourcedigit.com/16254-install-avidemux-2-6-10-video-editor-on-ubuntu-15-04-and-ubuntu-14-10/):

Install Avidemux 2.6.10 Video Editor (GTK) on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet

```
$ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
 $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6
```

Install Avidemux 2.6.10 Video Editor (QT) on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet

```
$ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
 $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt
```

Install Avidemux 2.6.10 Video Editor (GTK) on Ubuntu 14.04 and Derivatives

Run the following commands in Terminal to install Avidemux (GKT) on Ubuntu 14.04, Linux Mint 17.1, Linux Mint 17 and Derivative systems:

```
 $ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
 $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6
```

Install Avidemux 2.6.10 Video Editor (QT) on Ubuntu 14.04 and Derivatives

Run the following commands in Terminal to install Avidemux (QT) on Ubuntu 14.04, Linux Mint 17.1, Linux Mint 17 and Derivative systems:

```
$ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
 $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt
```

---

Also, deb files are available [here](http://deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/a/avidemux/), also [here](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-14.04/getdeb-apps-amd64/avidemux2.6_2.6.10-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb.html).

**Some more dependencies are needed to make it work**:

```
avidemux3-core-2.6.10-YYMMDD-runtime
avidemux3-plugins-COMMON-2.6.10-YYMMDD-plugins
avidemux3-qt4-2.6.10-YYMMDD-runtime
avidemux3-plugins-QT4-2.6.10-YYMMDD-plugins
avidemux3-cli-2.6.10-YYMMDD-runtime
avidemux3-plugins-CLI-2.6.10-YYMMDD-plugins
avidemux3-settings-2.6.10--YYMMDD-settings
```

As a 2.6.10 deb with dependencies included: [here](http://avidemux.org/smif/index.php?topic=16445.0)

---

In Arch-based systems installable from AUR. I have tried [this version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/avidemux-2.6) but that wouldn't work as expected. The avidemux-qt4-git  2.6.10.151013.269f93bc987-1 version worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the [snapshot](http://www.avidemux.org/nightly/snapshot/) compilable on Linux? Looks like it is intended for it...

Comment: sorry, maybe it is but compiling is beyond my skill, so I'll adjust the question for a compiled version.

Comment: Usually compiling involves nothing but execute a couple of commands. Try entering the directory, execute `./configure` if no errors appear then execute `make` and if no errors appear then finally execute `make install`. If any of the previous steps go wrong then keep looking for the binaries, otherwise you have compiled and installed your first program from sources :P

Comment: thanks for the encouraging idea that those three simple commands ***might*** very well work one fine day. I will also try [the 2.6.x compilation instructions](http://avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=build:install_2.6) and report

Comment: Looks like this one comes with its own scripts to do the process, you shouldn't have any problem following those instructions and comply with the libraries dependencies. Anyway, those three script/commands might come in handy if you ever run into any other source that you want to compile.

Comment: Mmmmmmm, the scripts are trying to create .deb files for you to install avidemux instead of just compiling it. As the message goes, you might better download cmake and compile it or.... risk using the one you already have and see if you get errors. That is just a warning, it may work....

Comment: I couldn't solve it but the answer was that that it was already compiled and made available. See my answer on that.